# Wiping Mac OS completely and installing Ubuntu: Will the webcam work?

Tags: system-installation, mac, webcam, macbook, macosx

What I have: old MacBook (3,1), Intel Core 2 Duo, 2GHz, 1 processor. OS: 10.5.8

The macbook is old and has a lot of problems (ignoring the fact that the OS cannot be updated without paying, the disk cannot be fragmented without formatting [which would make me lose the OS anyway, as I don't have a CD to reinstall it] so I cannot arrange a dual boot [yes, I have tried every conventional and unconventional way to resize/partition/etc.]).

Thus, I'd like to wipe out the entire OS and install Ubuntu. However, I'm wondering whether I need to be wary of some incompatibilities. More concretely, I have two questions:

1. Will the webcam and microphone work? Do I need to prepare something beforehand while I still have Mac OS available? I have to attend meetings via video conferences quite often, so this is a must.
2. Anything else to consider/prepare before formatting and installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Can't you resize and move your installation to make some space for Ubuntu and create a dualboot? Are you familiar with live sessions from CD or USB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)?

Comment: No, sadly the disk isn't allowing any of the methods I have tried out so far (and this was a fairly exhaustive experimentation). Trying out the live session is a good idea though, thanks.

Comment: You'll be able to format the disk from the live session with the `gparted` program (MAKE A BACKUP OF THE WHOLE DISK! before formatting, take a recent Ubuntu 14.04.1 iso image to burn on CD or to put on your USB stick)

Answer (score 1):

Boot into a live session from CD or USB stick (instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) and check if it works. No need to wipe anything, it will leave you Mac OS untouched.

If the webcam doesn't work in the live session it isn't an indication that it's impossible to make it work, but if it does in the Ubuntu live session it most certainly will in the Ubuntu installation (no matter if you wipe Mac OS or keep it in dualboot).